# Firefox requesting content inside HTML5 template before activation

Tags: firefox, html5-template

I was debugging my web app using DevTools when I noticed that Firefox is requesting url defined in src attribute of an img that is located inside a HTML5 template tag, while Chrome doesn't.

I'm using the last version (50.0).

Is this a bug?

Example below:

```
<template id="object-img">
  <div class='object-container'>
    <div>
      <img src="cacaca.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="imagem" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Well you'd have to show us some code so we can see if you did anything wrong ... But unless you render the template explicitly somehow, the browser is not supposed to render it on its own, let alone request any external resources based on the template content.

Comment: As requested, I put an example (edited on my own question). The template isn't rendered - it's render via javascript onclick event.

Comment: Another useful information: my code has others templates. Video, audio, object... But only the img has this behavior.

Comment: Then this should not happen.

Answer (score 0):

It's a kind of optimization from Firefox.

The `image` is requested only the first time if it is not already in the browser's history / cache. Subsequent reload of the page won't trigger the request again.

The problem is that the `image` inside the `<template>` is requested before the following but *normal* images in the rendered DOM, which could be counterproductive in some situations. A solution is to put the `<template>` after the other images.

*Note:* the `template` specifications state that the elements in the template are not rendered, but they are parsed. They say nothing about preloading of referenced resources.